# Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano.VrPanoramaView

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, google-vr

Recently I am developing with Xamarin a 360 degree display of video and images having imported to the library now correctly panowidget inside the program. The layout is set up so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano.VrPanoramaView
      android:id="@+id/pano_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="250dp">
  </com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano.VrPanoramaView>
</LinearLayout>
```

while the main activity looks like this

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Google.VR.SDK.Widgets.Pano;
using Android.Graphics;

namespace App10
 {

[Activity(Label = "App10", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{

    VrPanoramaView.Options options = new VrPanoramaView.Options();
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {

        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        VrPanoramaView panoramaView = FindViewById<VrPanoramaView>(Resource.Id.pano_view);
        options.InputType = VrPanoramaView.Options.TypeMono;

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile("/Resources/drawable/testRoom1_2kMono.jpg");
        panoramaView.LoadImageFromBitmap(myBitmap, options);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        // SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
    }
}
}
```

when I fill out his execution I get these runtime error

```
#1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano.VrPanoramaView
```

Is there a solution about this silly problem?

Comment: Did you add the Google VR SDK to your app? What is the full stack trace?

Comment: Yep i add the Google VR SDK reference about the PanoWidgetView, and also i've this kind of error in execution. The import and the using about code compute and compile was correct

Comment: But did you add it through NuGet or did you make your own biding or where do you get it from? Just adding a using statement doesn't add a reference to a dll.

Comment: I make my own binding from the file .aar abouit Google VR and it works correct (maybe). Also i ve the create the .dll from that, load on my project and methods and class works well. I didn't add any NuGet except the Xamarin.Android.Support components

Comment: I use the panowidget.aar version 1.30.0 from the site of developers https://developers.google.com/vr/android/release-notes